# WSO2BPS timeouts and wait nodes are note processed after restart

Tags: wso2, apache-ode, wso2-business-process

Using WSO2 BPS 3.6.0 we encountered a serious issue

We have a few processes waiting for external events (with timeout) and several processes polling for updates (using wait node).

The problem arises as soon we restart a server:
 * timeouts which are passed during the downtime are not processed
 * wait nodes are not processed at all

Reading related articels:

- https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RIFTSAW-466
- [wso2 wait loop doesn't work after restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134331/wso2-wait-loop-doesnt-work-after-restart)

I found that the timeout timestamps are stored in the *ode_job* table. So I tried to update the timeout timestamps (before starting up the BPS server)

`update ode_job set ts=(near_future_timestamp) where ts>(before_restart) and ts<(near_future_timestamp)`

which resolved the scope timeouts, however the **wait nodes are not processed anymore** even they were stated in future. That effectively blocks all the polling instances without any means to move them further.

Is there a way to "revive" or timeout the wait nodes after restarting the server?

Comment: Missed it earlier. Will see if there is a problem in ODE, but for that I would need a sample process that reproduces the problem and the exact steps. Can you provide it?